# Android onStart executes faster than a broadcast

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

So I am calling a native device selector `android.bluetooth.devicepicker.action.LAUNCH` with will broadcast `android.bluetooth.devicepicker.action.DEVICE_SELECTED` action to a extended Broadcast reciver `DeviceReceiver.java`. The receiver receives the selected device details and sets a static public boolean `isDeviceSelected = true`

As the device selector closes the activity view goes live again and triggers `onStart();`

There I check `if (DeviceReceiver.isDeviceSelected == true) { connectToDevice(); }`

So the issue is that sometimes (5%) the `onStart` executes before DeviceReceiver sets `isDeviceSelected=true`.

How do I make onStart to execute only when DeviceReceiver execution is done?

Comment: What exactly is `isDeviceSelected=true` used for in the flow of your app?

Comment: it's just a flag that a bluetooth device was selected and is ready to be used.

Comment: I ask, because if it isn't immediately necessary for anything shown on the screen, use a Listener, which sends the result back to the Activity once its done.